# fatal: unable to access <git repo url> SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate for particular network

Tags: git, ssl-certificate

When attempting to execute `git pull` or `git push` commands on a specific network, I encounter the error message `"unable to get local issuer certificate."` Strangely, when using a different network, these operations work seamlessly.

How can I troubleshoot and resolve this issue?

Comment: It expect this is a corporate proxy that replaces the SSL cert so they can do content inspection. Are you on windows? If so, try enabling the SChannel implementation to allow git to use the Windows Certificate Store.